# How to replace a dummy name if a csv file contains a blank field?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Here is a CSV file which contains several rows but the problem is each row contains 6 fields, but there are some fields which contain some missing fields.So while uploading the results to database I want to replace the missing fields with a tombsotne like 'NA'.

Here I am showing the code i have written.

```
with open("results/somename.csv","r") as f:
        for record in f:
            #print record.split()[0]
            record = record.split("|")
            file1 = record[0]
            file2 = record[1]
            file3 = record[2]
            file4 = record[3]
            file5 = record[4]
            if not record[5] :
                file6 = record[5]
            else:
                file6 = 'NA'
            if not record[6] :
                file7 = record[6]
            else:
                file7 =  'NA'
```

Here I am splitting the file based on the delimiter `|` and then trying to split the file into fields which can be used in the database.Now due to insufficient information record[5] and record[6] are not available in some rows(not all).So iam checking if it contains any string otherwise replacing with `'NA'`.But during execution the error came.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_kiran.py", line 15, in <module>
    if not record[5] :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So all i want to is to replace with 'NA' in the missing fields.

Comment: Please check length of array after split. Use if to perform intended operations.

Comment: @SanketSudake Thanks.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for the answer,i have already used 1st comment and changed my code.

Comment: But do consider using LOAD DATA INFILE instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code

```
with open("results/somename.csv","r") as f:
    for record in f:
        #print record.split()[0]
        record = record.split("|")
        file1 = record[0]
        file2 = record[1]
        file3 = record[2]
        file4 = record[3]
        file5 = record[4]
        try:
            file6 = record[5]
        except IndexError as e:
            file6 = 'NA'
            file7 = 'NA'
            continue
        try:
            file7 = record[6]
        except IndexError as e:
            file7 = 'NA'
       'do something'
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

A lot of hard work for something that the database supports natively by *default*. Simply change the columns in question to have a default value of NA. That will ensure that the column shows up as NA when you insert a NULL into it

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ALTER COLUMN my_column set DEFAULT 'NA'
```

That makes much of the code redundant, but wait, you don't need to iterate through a file manually and split them line by line to do this. Python has excellent support for [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that reduces your code by a few more lines.

But wait....

you can do this in a single mysql command. No need for even a single line of python code

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somename.csv' INTO TABLE 'Table1'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

> The [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Jay's code for generic approach ...

```
def get_file(record, index, default="N/A"):        
    try:
         if not record[index]: # not sure above this line, copied from your code
             return record[index]
    except IndexError:
         return default


with open("results/somename.csv","r") as f:
        # <your code>...

        # Posible index error
        file6 = get_file(record, 5)
        # Even you can check here 
        # if file6 == 'N/A':
        #    <code to return all next files as N/A>
        file7 = get_file(record, 6)
```